# Stop All Code Execution Until IFrame Completely Loads

Tags: javascript, c#, html, iframe, webforms

I am loading a `webform` and on this page I have an `iFrame`  How can I delay the next line of my code from executing until the `iFrame` has completely loaded?  I tried this `javascript` but it does not wait until the `iFrame` is totally rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('frame1').onload = function () {

}
```

**EDIT**
using the syntax below it writes the code to my window instead of actually executing it?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('frame1').onload = function () {
        myWindow.close();
        window.returnValue = true;
        window.close();
}
});
```

Would it be possible to send a response to my client side **C#** code once the `iFrame` has fully loaded and I run my close() function from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery library
Wrap you function with this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('frame1').onload = function () {

    }
});
```

Don't forget to add jQuery library to your application. You can use the online one provided by Microsoft.

```
<head><script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script></head>
```

Comment: Same issue.  It just writes $(document ).ready etc to my web form, the code inside never executes..